# Parsing HTML using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the following HTML that I'm trying to parse using the HTML Agility Pack.

This is a snippet of the whole file that is returned by the code:

```
<div class="story-body fnt-13 p20-b user-gen">
    <p>text here text here text </p>
    <p>text here text here text text here text here text text here text here text text here text here text </p>
    <div  class="gallery clr bdr aln-c js-no-shadow mod  cld">
        <div>
            <ol>
                <li class="fader-item aln-c ">
                    <div class="imageWrap m10-b">
                       &#8203;<img class="http://www.domain.com/picture.png| " src="http://www.domain.com/picture.png" alt="alt text" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="caption">caption text</p>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div >
    <p>text here text here text text here text here text text here text here text text here text here text </p>
    <p>text here text here text text here text here text text here text here text text here text here text text here text here text </p>
    <p>text here text here text text here text here text text here text here text text here text here text text here text here text </p>
</div>
```

I get this snippet of code using the following (which is messy i know)

```
string url = "http://www.domain.com/story.html";
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load(url);

var links = document.DocumentNode
        .Descendants("div")
        .Where(div => div.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("story-body fnt-13 p20-b user-gen")) //
        .SelectMany(div => div.Descendants("p"))
        .ToList();
int cn = links.Count;

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection tl = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]");
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in tl)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(node.InnerText.Trim());
    textBox1.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

The code loops through each `p` and (for now) appends it to a textbox. All is working correctly other than the `div` tag with the class `gallery clr bdr aln-c js-no-shadow mod  cld`. The result of this bit of HTML is that I get the `&#8203;` and caption text bits.

what's the best way to omit that from the results?

Comment: Psst...`So two questions, what's the best way to omit that from the results?` That's one question, what is the other?

Comment: i have no idea what your talking about.... :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPATH is your friend. Try this and forget about that crappy xlink syntax :-)

```
HtmlNodeCollection tl = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[not(@*)]");
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in tl)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
}
```

This expression will select all P nodes that don't have any attributes set. See here for other samples: [XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: thanks that works a treat, will look into xpath too as it looks a far better solution!

Comment: it did work but it also includes other P nodes from over the page. It was only a snippet posted at the top.

Comment: Just add other filters to the expression (what's between the [ and ] characters)

Comment: with xpath is there a way to get a collection of nodes from within a certain div with a certain class. i.e <div class="story-body fnt-13 p20-b user-gen">

Comment: Sure. SelectNodes("//div[@class='story']") will get all div from the root with a 'class' attribute that has the 'story' value.

Comment: really sorry to have to ask yet another question on this, i've been looking at combining filters between the []. Do you use a /filter/filter method?

Comment: Sorted it with "//div[@class='story-body fnt-13 p20-b user-gen']//p[not(@*)]" liking this xpath malarky! certainly easier/cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you're asking. I *think* you're asking how to get just the direct descendants of a particular div. If that's the case, then use `ChildNodes` rather than `Descendants`. That is:

```
.SelectMany(div => div.ChildNodes().Where(n => n.Name == "p"))
```

The problem is that `Descendants` does a fully recursive walk of the document tree.

Comment: easier wold be with xpath: //p

Comment: that would include <p class="caption">caption text</p>. i'm trying to not include anything from the 4th line to the 15th line (divs) just the other <p>'s

Comment: @Nathan: No, I don't think it would include those. `ChildNodes` only gets the *direct descendants* of a particular node. If you replace the `SelectMany` in your LINQ expression with my `SelectMany`, I think you'll find that it will work as advertised. My expression uses `Where` because there is no `ChildNodes` overload that lets you specify the type (i.e. you can't say, `ChildNodes("p")`).

Comment: ok, i think i understand what your saying. Like the following?    var links = document.DocumentNode
            .Descendants("div")
            .Where(div => div.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("story-body fnt-13 p20-b user-gen")) //
            .SelectMany(div => div.ChildNodes.Where(n => n.Name == "p"))
            .ToList();